# Parsing GML encoded WFS response XML file

Tags: xml, swift, xml-parsing, wms, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I need some help getting weather details temperature etc. out of this GML encoded WMS response XML file. This what I get from weather service that provides open data with Catalog Service for Web (CSW), Web Map Service (WMS) and Web Feature Service (WFS). Unlike JSON/XML, I have no idea what is happening in this file. Please suggest some solution for Swift 3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection
    timeStamp="2017-07-31T15:48:01Z"
    numberMatched="1"
    numberReturned="1"
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:om="http://www.opengis.net/om/2.0"
    xmlns:omso="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/omso/3.0"
    xmlns:ompr="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/ompr/3.0"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
    xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
    xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
    xmlns:swe="http://www.opengis.net/swe/2.0"
    xmlns:gmlcov="http://www.opengis.net/gmlcov/1.0"
    xmlns:sam="http://www.opengis.net/sampling/2.0"
    xmlns:sams="http://www.opengis.net/samplingSpatial/2.0"
    xmlns:target="http://xml.fmi.fi/namespace/om/atmosphericfeatures/1.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd
    http://www.opengis.net/gmlcov/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/gmlcov/1.0/gmlcovAll.xsd
    http://www.opengis.net/sampling/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/sampling/2.0/samplingFeature.xsd
    http://www.opengis.net/samplingSpatial/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/samplingSpatial/2.0/spatialSamplingFeature.xsd
    http://www.opengis.net/swe/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/sweCommon/2.0/swe.xsd
    http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/omso/3.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/omso/3.0/SpecialisedObservations.xsd
    http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/ompr/3.0 http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/ompr/3.0/Processes.xsd
    http://xml.fmi.fi/namespace/om/atmosphericfeatures/1.0 http://xml.fmi.fi/schema/om/atmosphericfeatures/1.0/atmosphericfeatures.xsd">

    <wfs:member>
        <omso:GridSeriesObservation gml:id="WFS-l9pen.SrlipXUb8ZfAc8nS2h_8.JTowuYWbbpdOs2_llx4efR060aeWzDtdOufXlmw48rp1w36d3R0629dnTTw36d3THv7ZeWHPlhaWLLn07qmnbltQ_wp37hjvCY2PlzrUi0Kcd06aMmrhnZd2Spp25bUP8KhE4V2nBm07sk7Lh5ZefSth2ackhmZ8u_Tk51mNmbRy2ZujXl899_LJf39svLvy09MOLZliaWzL2y7KnnhlqZmzfjw7MtambTfjSV3XpmcNbbh8RNPPph3Y8tK1dCA1tunnz07s9TL46VjTsM5lbd.TLsrM0aeWzDtZXDDyw7a1I.XfwkZdOfR0rWqZdvDLyw9OvLLWhQ5ZefPryy1oSOu3Tk09PNbVfTuyRNPLLj6ad.6tavp3ZKfDLlyTadZ1fTuyVZtOs6vp3ZK02nWtNw.NO3rtr6d2StCvp3ZI_Xn0rQiZe9Dfp3dK3qm_ph2Q9m_rkh7.2XlW5Xy4emjLyp.duLfsZ1tTN_eHs39ckPf2y8q4JuXJp67Yezf1yQ9_bLyrckac.iHs39ckPf2y8q3qHLLj08NPTD0079zHRXNQ5Zcenhp6Yemnfug7d_Xd0r2pYcmnD00790fZvxYdkHHj67euzD00791d1LDk04emnfumV4OPH129dmHpp37qwwqWHJpw9NO_dOy9KfXlmw48syvBx4.u3rsw9NO_dWGFSw5NOHpp37p2XpT68s2HHlp14OPH129dmHpp37q.KWHJpw9NO_dE05s3Xnlg48fXb12YemnfubnPpv5ZcnHrl5eb.nJXmFm26XTrNv5ZceHn0dOtGnlsw7XTrn15ZsOPK6dcN.nd0dOtvXZ008N.nd0x7.2Xlhz5Wh007ctPpl4T8hNDpp25bW_dlrGq1IYA-">
                     <om:phenomenonTime>
                <gml:TimePeriod gml:id="time-interval-1-1">
                    <gml:beginPosition>2017-07-31T16:00:00Z</gml:beginPosition>
                    <gml:endPosition>2017-08-02T03:00:00Z</gml:endPosition>
                </gml:TimePeriod>
            </om:phenomenonTime>
            <om:resultTime>
                <gml:TimeInstant gml:id="time-1-1">
                    <gml:timePosition>2017-07-31T12:00:00Z</gml:timePosition>
                </gml:TimeInstant>
            </om:resultTime>

        <om:procedure xlink:href="http://xml.fmi.fi/inspire/process/hirlam"/>
            <om:parameter>
                <om:NamedValue>
                    <om:name xlink:href="http://xml.fmi.fi/inspire/process/hirlam"/>
                    <om:value>
                        <gml:TimeInstant gml:id="analysis-time-1-1">
                            <gml:timePosition>2017-07-31T12:00:00Z</gml:timePosition>
                        </gml:TimeInstant>
                    </om:value>
                </om:NamedValue>
            </om:parameter>
            <om:observedProperty  xlink:href="http://data.fmi.fi/fmi-apikey/e35dc8fd-a855-4db5-a327-418120f64a86/meta?observableProperty=forecast&amp;param=GeopHeight,Temperature,Pressure,Humidity,WindDirection,WindSpeedMS,WindUMS,WindVMS,MaximumWind,WindGust,DewPoint,TotalCloudCover,WeatherSymbol3,LowCloudCover,MediumCloudCover,HighCloudCover,Precipitation1h,PrecipitationAmount,RadiationGlobalAccumulation,RadiationLWAccumulation,RadiationNetSurfaceLWAccumulation,RadiationNetSurfaceSWAccumulation,RadiationDiffuseAccumulation&amp;language=eng"/>
                    <om:featureOfInterest>
                <sams:SF_SpatialSamplingFeature gml:id="enn-s-1-1-">
          <sam:sampledFeature>
        <target:LocationCollection gml:id="sampled-target-1-1">
            <target:member>
            <target:Location gml:id="forloc-geoid-634963-pos">
                <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://xml.fmi.fi/namespace/stationcode/geoid">634963</gml:identifier>
            <gml:name codeSpace="http://xml.fmi.fi/namespace/locationcode/name">Tampere</gml:name>
            <gml:name codeSpace="http://xml.fmi.fi/namespace/locationcode/geoid">634963</gml:name>
            <target:representativePoint xlink:href="#point-634963"/>
            <target:country codeSpace="http://xml.fmi.fi/namespace/location/country">Finland</target:country>
            <target:timezone>Europe/Helsinki</target:timezone>
            <target:region codeSpace="http://xml.fmi.fi/namespace/location/region">Finland</target:region>              
            </target:Location></target:member>
        </target:LocationCollection>
       </sam:sampledFeature>
                <sams:shape>
                    <gml:MultiPoint gml:id="sf-1-1-">
                        <gml:pointMembers>  
                           <gml:Point gml:id="point-634963" srsName="http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4258" srsDimension="2">
                               <gml:name>Tampere</gml:name>
                               <gml:pos>61.49911 23.78712 </gml:pos>
                           </gml:Point>
                        </gml:pointMembers>
                    </gml:MultiPoint>
                </sams:shape>
            </sams:SF_SpatialSamplingFeature>
        </om:featureOfInterest>
              <om:result>
        <gmlcov:MultiPointCoverage gml:id="mpcv-1-1">
          <gml:domainSet>
            <gmlcov:SimpleMultiPoint gml:id="mp-1-1" srsName="http://xml.fmi.fi/gml/crs/compoundCRS.php?crs=4258&amp;time=unixtime" srsDimension="3">
              <gmlcov:positions>
                61.49911 23.78712  1501516800
                61.49911 23.78712  1501520400
                61.49911 23.78712  1501524000
                61.49911 23.78712  1501527600
                61.49911 23.78712  1501531200
              </gmlcov:positions>
            </gmlcov:SimpleMultiPoint>
          </gml:domainSet>
          <gml:rangeSet>
            <gml:DataBlock>
              <gml:rangeParameters/>
              <gml:doubleOrNilReasonTupleList>
                113.01 18.26 1007.03 92.74 259.0 3.79 
                113.01 17.79 1007.48 90.02 250.0 3.04 
                113.01 17.13 1007.82 93.62 229.0 2.19 
                113.01 16.42 1008.18 95.53 216.0 2.26 
                113.01 15.9 1008.89 97.09 211.0 2.74 
              </gml:doubleOrNilReasonTupleList>
            </gml:DataBlock>
          </gml:rangeSet>
          <gml:coverageFunction>
            <gml:CoverageMappingRule>
              <gml:ruleDefinition>Linear</gml:ruleDefinition>
            </gml:CoverageMappingRule>
          </gml:coverageFunction>
          <gmlcov:rangeType>
            <swe:DataRecord>
              <swe:field name="GeopHeight"  xlink:href="http://"/>
              <swe:field name="Temperature"  xlink:href="http://"/>
              <swe:field name="Pressure"  xlink:href="http://"/>
              <swe:field name="Humidity"  xlink:href="http://"/>
              <swe:field name="WindDirection"  xlink:href="http://"/>
              <swe:field name="WindSpeedMS"  xlink:href="http://"/>
              </swe:DataRecord>
          </gmlcov:rangeType>
        </gmlcov:MultiPointCoverage>
      </om:result>

        </omso:GridSeriesObservation>
    </wfs:member>

</wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with swift, but I can maybe point you to how to read this file:

What you basically need is these three elements:

```
  <gmlcov:positions>
    61.49911 23.78712  1501516800
    61.49911 23.78712  1501520400
    61.49911 23.78712  1501524000
    61.49911 23.78712  1501527600
    61.49911 23.78712  1501531200
  </gmlcov:positions>

  <gml:doubleOrNilReasonTupleList>
        113.01 18.26 1007.03 92.74 259.0 3.79 
        113.01 17.79 1007.48 90.02 250.0 3.04 
        113.01 17.13 1007.82 93.62 229.0 2.19 
        113.01 16.42 1008.18 95.53 216.0 2.26 
        113.01 15.9 1008.89 97.09 211.0 2.74 
   </gml:doubleOrNilReasonTupleList>

 <swe:DataRecord>
    <swe:field name="GeopHeight"  xlink:href="http://"/>
    <swe:field name="Temperature"  xlink:href="http://"/>
    <swe:field name="Pressure"  xlink:href="http://"/>
    <swe:field name="Humidity"  xlink:href="http://"/>
    <swe:field name="WindDirection"  xlink:href="http://"/>
    <swe:field name="WindSpeedMS"  xlink:href="http://"/>
 </swe:DataRecord>
```

The first one tells you the position and the time of the measurement:

> 61.49911 23.78712  1501516800

```
Latitude: 61.49911
Longitude: 23.7812
Unixtime:   1501516800 --> which translates to: Mon Jul 31 16:00:00 2017 UTC
```

The second one is the actual measurement data, and the third one gives you the meaning of the measurement.
So this is what you get for the first measurement:

```
 GeopHeight | Temperature | Pressure | Humidity | WindDirection | WindSpeedMs
 113.01     | 18.26       | 1007.03  | 92.74    | 259.0         | 3.79
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, its easy to see parameters and values. Problem is to fetch them out (

Comment: Ach okay. Sorry I misunderstood.